# How to get rid of static variable in my java code?

Tags: java

Guys:

I would ask a question that may sounds silly. I need to remove using a class static variable which is a counter by senior teammate. he said I should only use static member when necessary, and it is thread unsafe. All I can figure out is to use synchronized key word. I would know if there is better solution. Here is below is my current code.

```
package gov.faa.infra.ifp.domain.dao.isc;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import gov.faa.infra.ifp.message.MessageCollectionBean;

public abstract class IdentifiableTest<T>{

private static int recordedMessageLength=0; 
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IdentifiableTest.class.getName());

abstract public void checkIndividualIdentifiable(T identifiableObject);

public void checkIdentifiable(T identifiableObject){
    checkMessageCollection();
    checkIndividualIdentifiable(identifiableObject);
}

public void checkIdentifiableList(List<T> identifiableList){
    checkMessageCollection();
    assertNotNull(identifiableList);
    assertTrue(identifiableList.size()>0);

    for (int i=0; i<identifiableList.size(); i++){          
        checkIndividualIdentifiable(identifiableList.get(i));
    }
}

public void checkMessageCollection(){

    if (MessageCollectionBean.getMessages()!=null){
        if (MessageCollectionBean.getMessages().length>recordedMessageLength){
            int i=MessageCollectionBean.getMessages().length-1;
            for (String message: MessageCollectionBean.getMessages()){
                if(i>=recordedMessageLength){
                    logger.debug(message+"##"+i+"th message in the total of "+MessageCollectionBean.getMessages().length+" messages. recordedMessageLength="+recordedMessageLength+"####Message Collection Bean");
                }
                i--;
            }
            recordedMessageLength=MessageCollectionBean.getMessages().length;
        }
    }

    assertTrue(MessageCollectionBean.getMessages()==null || MessageCollectionBean.getMessages().length==recordedMessageLength);
}

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do/achieve. Removing a static variable is not *what* - it's *how*. Please avoid the "how" part and focus on the "what", doing so will provide us more context about the bigger picture and will help us help you.

Comment: The question really does not point out what you are trying to ask. - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also... static variables exist as a single entity ( Even if you have 100 instances of the class... there will be only 1 instance of the static var)... You probably want a separate counter for each instance of your class.

Comment: Looks like you do have to use `static` variable in your case, only that [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is computed by `checkMessageCollection()` so make it a result of the method call.

Comment: That's not helpful: the result of a method call will not save the state.

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks for your help. yes, I got stuck due to keeping state without using static variable.

Comment: @alfasin - that's the point.  There is no *need* to keep the state in this class.  Return it, and let the caller save the state.  The only other way to avoid a static is to either pass in some object to hold the state, or create instances of the class containing these methods.

Comment: I have nearly 100 methods calling checkMessageCollection, if I let saver save the state, that means I have to let caller to get message length before any operation followed by calling checkMessageCollection, and I have to update all these places? also I have to synchronize all these code?

Comment: You only store the value if it is needed for the time that it is needed.  If the result is not needed  by the caller, don't save it.